# Upgrade of BOOST 1.35 to 1.43 causes linker error with __pRawDllMain (mfc related)

Tags: mfc, boost-thread, static-linking, dynamic-linking

At work we have an MFC Extension DLL that built fine with 1.35 but when built with 1.43 causes the following error:

```
error LNK2005: __pRawDllMain already defined in ApObs.obj
```

If I activate BOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC the old build lists:

```
linking to lib file: libboost_thread-vc71-mt-gd-1_35.lib
```

and

```
linking to lib file: libboost_thread-vc71-mt-gd-1_43.lib
```

So no change there with which library is linked

The full error message is:

```
libboost_thread-vc71-mt-gd-1_43.lib(tss_pe.obj) : error LNK2005: __pRawDllMain already defined in ApObs.obj
```

I have done a diff on tss_pe.cpp in both library versions and they are identical, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

You can get the message to disappear by defining `BOOST_THREAD_USE_DLL` but then we would need to ship BOOST_THREAD-VC71-MT-GD-1_43.DLL so I don't think this is the best solution.

Comment: you mention 1.36 two times, but the linker output says 1.35?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of the linking order.
You can change the linking error by manually adding the libs in the **Additional Dependencies**.
In my case putting libboost_thread-vc71-mt-gd-1_43.lib BEFORE the other conflicting lib solved the problem:

**Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies**

**libboost_thread-vc80-mt-1_40.lib;mfcs80u.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)**

Note that in my case it was conflicting with mfcs80u.lib

Comment: I am no longer at that company, and I think in the end they just moved over to the DLL version, but I think your answer is correct so I will mark it as such

Answer (score 2):

There is known incompatibility between MFC and statically linked boost Thread, both trying to hook into DllMain to initialize stuff. This has been introduced in boost 1.37.

[From the author of boost::thread:](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.threads.devel/389%20title)

> If you can ensure that 
>   on_process_exit from boost/thread/detail/tss_hooks.hpp is called when 
>   the DLL is unloaded then you can patch libs/thread/src/win32/tss_pe.cpp 
>   to remove the use of _pRawDllMain.

(He recommends to use the DLL version, though.)

There seem to have been [efforts](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Fwd-Thread-Solution-to-conflict-with-MFC-td3477977.html) to make this patching unnecessary, but apparently to no avail so far...

Comment: Beginning with Boost 1.52 [this is possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34769235/1969455).