# Adding #include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp> breaks my ActiveX control?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, mfc, activex

**Is there a known problem with the boost::mutex header when used inside an ActiveX control?

(Boost version v1.39)**

If I create an *MFC ActiveX Control* project in Visual Studio 2008 called *"DefaultOCXControl"* then I can build it, the control registers itself as part of the build, and can be inserted into the ActiveX Test Container as you would expect. All good.

If I then just add this line:

```
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
```

at the top of my `DefaultOCXControlCtrl.h` file and rebuild: the registration step at the end of the build fails with:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>   Program: C:\Windows\system32\regsvr32.exe
>   File: f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\dllinit.cpp
>   Line: 587

The offending assertion looks like this:

```
void AFXAPI AfxCoreInitModule()
{
    ASSERT(AfxGetModuleState() != AfxGetAppModuleState());
    ...
```

Attempting to insert the control into the ActiveX Test Container now results in the same message.  If I remove the line and rebuild then everything is fine - so it definitely seems to be something in that header file that causes the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried linking `boost::thread` dynamically (define BOOST_THREAD_DYN_LINK)?

I had this kind of problems when using `boost::thread` with a mixed C++/.NET project and linking just `boost::thread` dynamically was the solution (here a possible explanation: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.user/22617/match=clr)

Comment: Thanks. This was the solution in the end. Apparently there is a known problem with boost::thread and MFC as they both hang clean-up off functions of `_pRawDllMain`, discussed on the boost mail archive here: http://lists.boost.org/threads-devel/2009/06/0476.php I migrated our static library that was using boost::thread to a DLL instead and that sorted the issue.

Answer (score 7):

Since Boost 1.52 you could try adding this line to your code, especially if you prefer static linking:

```
#include <boost/thread/win32/mfc_thread_init.hpp>
```

Source: [Boost Ticket 8550](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/8550)

Comment: Works like a charm with boost 1.55 and VS2013.

Comment: Where should I put this line?

Comment: @user1633272 If I'm not mistaken it does not really matter, as long as it gets compiled into the binary that is experiencing the problem.

Comment: shoud I include it in dll project or the project which is using the dll? Currently I have a EasyHook dll project B which depends on MFC static library project A(Use MFC in a Shared DLL), I added this line in project B, but doesn't work. One more error occurs: LNK2005 _DllMain@12 already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(dll_dllmain_stub.obj)

Comment: According to the linked Boost Ticket adding it to your DLL should suffice. If it doesn't then probably this solution does not work for you, sorry.