# My process crash before main ,by datamngr.dll

Tags: c++, windows, boost, boost-thread

My process crashes before main, on boost  code:
 myexe.exe!boost::`anonymous namespace'::run_thread_exit_callbacks()  + 0xe6 bytes  C++

The process written in c++ native for windows

The only strange thing I noticed , that my exe load dll that is not mine:
***datamngr.dll(version 1.0.0.1)***

I'am sure that this is a malisiouse dll , that is injected to me through appinit.
Is there any idea why it could crash me on boost code ?

B.R.
Roman

Comment: try searching the dll and find the directory where it is located. Once you found it, the install location might give you a hint where this belongs to.

Comment: It could be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355931/adding-include-boost-thread-mutex-hpp-breaks-my-activex-control/5358637#5358637

Answer (score 0):

Datamngr.dll is a dll from a third party application that hooks into your process (probably using the `AppInit_dll` mechanism). From [googling around](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-performance/what-is-this/d4c8b1d5-b745-4c8f-878a-f936ad49e87b) it appears that it's likely to be malware. The hooks mean that every process is loading this dll where it can monitor things like filesystem access. If it crashes then it'll bring down your process. I would run some AV and spyware scanners to fix this. I don't believe it's a problem with boost.