# MFC ASSERT in dllinit.cpp line 703 when using Boost.Log (or Boost.Thread)

Tags: c++, boost, mfc, boost-thread, boost-log

I receive an assertion in dllinit.cpp, when I try to use Boost.Log in one of my DLLs.

I have a tools.dll, which contains my logging facility and I tried to implement to logging stuff with Boost.Log.
This tools.dll is referenced by another helper.dll and both DLLs are used in the application.

However, when I start the application, I get the ASSERT.

This happens with Boost 1.54 and (included) Boost.Log as well as with Boost 1.48 and Boost.Log 1.1.

I've digged through lots of mailing lists and old postings. What I understood so far, there's an issue with _pRawDllMain pointer in Boost.Thread, some suggested commenting it out in

```
#include <boost/thread/detail/tss_hooks.hpp>
```

but this leads to memory leaks?
This [thread](http://lists.boost.org/threads-devel/2009/06/0476.php) said it would be fixed after 1.40, but I don't know, if this has been done.
Dynamic linking to Boost as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355931/adding-include-boost-thread-mutex-hpp-breaks-my-activex-control) did not help.

Asking on [boost-users](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2013/10/80277.php) did not help so far.

Any hints, what I should check?

**EDIT:**
It's configured as standard DLL, but there's a dependecy on MFC100.dll, because I use the API from afxwin.h to get version information of applications.

Comment: Please provide comments, why you downvote so I can improve my way of asking :)

Comment: What Kind of DLL did you create? MFC-Extension DLL? Standard DLL? MFC linked statically or dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I removed the dependency on MFC100.dll (GetVersionInfo works without afxwin.h) in the tools.dll, so there was no dependency on MFC100.dll in the helper.dll anymore.

Finally none of my DLLs depend on MFC, so the ASSERT also disappeared. Thanks xMRi!