# MFC using DLL fails to initialise, asserts in AfxCoreInitModule

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, mfc

This problem occurred when changing a dynamic library to a static library. The code compiles cleanly but during application startup an assertion is hit in `AfxCoreInitModule` when asserting `AfxGetModuleState() != AfxGetAppModuleState()` during the initialisation of a DLL which uses the static library. From that point on all resources fail to load.

The only mention of this occurring elsewhere seems to be due to a bug in the Boost.Thread library (such as in the question: [Adding #include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp> breaks my ActiveX control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355931/adding-include-boost-thread-mutex-hpp-breaks-my-activex-control)) and although some of Boost is used the threading library is not and so that is not the solution to this.

The static libraries themselves do not contain any MFC resources and only use some of the serialization functionality. They were originally set up to define their own `DllMain` which would call `AfxInitExtensionModule` unlike the calling DLL which is still using the MFC provided `DllMain` defined in dllmodul.cpp where this assertion failure is happening.

Comment: If your original dll used a CWinApp derived class you will need to remove that from the project files.

Comment: There is no class derived from CWinApp in use in that library.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint on `THREAD_LOCAL(_AFX_THREAD_STATE, _afxThreadState)` in `afxstat.cpp` and seeing where this is being called from.

Comment: @user1793036 I put a breakpoint on `THREAD_LOCAL(_AFX_THREAD_STATE, _afxThreadState)` and in both static and dynamic library builds it gets called from the same place. The stack looks like:

 mfc100ud.dll!`dynamic initializer for '_afxThreadState''()  Line 161 + 0x4 bytes C++
  msvcr100d.dll!_initterm(void (void)* * pfbegin, void (void)* * pfend)  Line 873 C
  mfc100ud.dll!_CRT_INIT(void * hDllHandle, unsigned long dwReason, void * lpreserved)  Line 289 C
  mfc100ud.dll!__DllMainCRTStartup(void * hDllHandle, unsigned long dwReason, void * lpreserved)  Line 506 + 0x13 bytes C 
...